# How much do clouds scatter UV light?

Tags: astronomy, diffraction, stars

I understand that clouds are more transparent to UV light than longer wavelengths, but are they transparent enough that you would be able to make out stars in UV at all?  What about the moon or the sun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it depends on the specific band.  400nm is right near visible and is scattered as you might expect from how you see clouds.  But the attenuation ramps very rapidly as the wavelength decreases.  By the time you get to 300nm the stratosphere absorbs almost 100% of UV.  You might be able to tell what direction the sun is, but imaging anything is right out.

The daytime sky is blue due to the increased scattering of short wavelengths.  This scattering is even stronger for UV.

One paper I found suggest that clouds will scatter UV about 15% to 30% as strongly as they do visible light.  So even if the stratosphere were transparent, thick clouds would still prevent viewing.  But you could probably image through very thin clouds if there were something to see.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a link to that paper? Also, are there any wavelengths that could be used for celestial navigation through clouds?